# cakephp htaccess file for website speed performance

Tags: performance, .htaccess, cakephp

I want htaccess file code so my website performance for caching , image ,css, js loading can be speed up. So my website performance should fast in google insights and Gtmetrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have setup mine htaccess file for my all projects.you can configure like this

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <ifModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 6 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    </ifModule>
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
      </filesMatch>
      Header unset ETag
    </ifModule>
    FileETag None

    # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

    # Or, compress certain file types by extension:
    <files *.html>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </files>
```

This may help you to speed up your website performance.Put it in root .htaccess file